# Where am I wrong in the process of solving this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve an ODE and apparently my answers are wrong, but I don't know where I'm wrong. This is the ODE, $$\sqrt {1-x^2}\,y'\;+\sqrt {1-y^2}=0$$ $$-1<x<1, -1<y<1$$
and the condition is $$y(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

The general answer is $$arcsin(x) + arcsin(y) = C$$

where C is a constant.
Until here, everthing is fine, but when I try to find the specific solution using the condition of the ODE, I found three answers where two of them are wrong. I don't know how did I go wrong. Is my way the right method, which is to find all these three answers and then try each one of them, or is there sth else that I missed. Please tell me. Thank you!
I took a photo of how I solve this equation.

[how I solve the ODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTUYq.jpg)

However, though, if I pause at the solutions for case 2 and case 3, where $$\arcsin(x) + arcsin(y) = C$$
in which C = $\pi$ in case 2 and C = $3\frac{\pi}{2}$ and differentiate it here, then case 2 and case 3 become solutions to the ODE, because C will become nothing when it is differentiated. I meant, if it is differentiated and become the ODE plus it fulfills the condition, should not it become the solutions?

Comment: Better to write the work out here, than to link to a photo offsite.

Comment: Why do you think all three answers should be correct? Hint : existence and uniqueness of solutions to first order ODEs.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Range of $\arcsin(x)$ is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @LANDOCHAN If my post answers your question satisfactorily you may upvote and accept my answer(ofc it is your wish).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation (15) to upvote the answer

Comment: You may accept the answer if you want

Comment: Done! @RamanujanXXV